# How can I get cups-devel package for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: printing, 22.04

I'm trying to install my very old HP printer on my new computer which is running Ubuntu 22.04. I installed HPLIP but that does not seem to support it. I am unable to install Gutenprint because it depends on cups-devel. I have not been able to find that package.

Comment: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libcups2-dev` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 If you post an answer, the question won't pop up as "unanswered" for eternity :)

Answer (score 2):

Please try:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libcups2-dev
```

Comment: its not solving the problem: its giving E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/hplip-isv/ppa/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.

Comment: Under Software and Updates, please uncheck that exact source, run `sudo apt update` and try again.